# Loading dynamic php-generated javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm making a website which must be as lightweight as possible. There is a portion of javascript code I want to turn into a module using a separate file, so the code will be loaded after a certain onClick event.

I can successfully load the javascript code:

```
var myscript = document.createElement('script');
myscript.src = "modules/mymodule.js";
document.head.appendChild(myscript);
```

My problem is that my javascript code has some language-dependent variables that I generate php. Is there a way of running php on my javascript file prior to dynamic loading, or is it too late? Maybe using AJAX?

Comment: What webserver are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For people who look at this answer; please do *not do this*. Only run PHP files through the PHP interpreter. Doing this is an unnecessary security risk.**

Depending on your web server, running PHP on JavaScript files is as simple as changing your webserver config.

Follow the instructions in this link: http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php5-iis7-configuration.php

However, when it prompts you to enter ***.php**, enter ***.js**.

By doing so, all your JavaScript files will be run through the PHP interpreter.

Comment: Sounds so simple, I'm going to try it. Thanks!

Comment: @Qaisa If the answer solves your problem remember to mark the question as solved for the reference of others.

Comment: I can confirm that it solved my problem.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you must send your variable names and some date to your php doc.
then manipulate these variable names in your code then generate the right javascript code.
you should use AJAX to send your variable names .

Comment: Try to rephrase your answer, as your answer stands it is quite hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could just render it in PHP, then load it in as a JavaScript file.

**MyScript.php**

```
<?php
  $number = 5;
  echo "var number = {$number}"
?>
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function loadScript(url){
      $.getScript( "MyScript.php", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
        console.log( number ); // 5
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>
</html>
```